# Kotlin Flow "there is more than one label with such a name in this scope" on collect

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a flow collection that I want to do a condition where if the list if empty to just return as there's no further work to be done.

my issue is that Android studio is tossing a nagging message at me

> there is more than one label with such a name in this scope

I'm assuming it's upset because I'm doing a collect within a collect (see code below, it'll hopefully make sense why I'm doing that).

is there a way to relabel the collect so it knows which one I'm talking about, I didn't see anything on it.

Also I'm new to flow so if I'm doing this wrong, let me know the proper way as this seems valid as I need one flow for the other one.

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    companyDataStore.getFromDataStore()
        .catch { e ->
            _snackBar.value = e.message
        }.collect { company ->
            companyFeatures = company.features

            userClient.getGroupsByFeatures(companyFeatures)
                .catch { e ->
                    _snackBar.value = e.message
                }
            .collect { groupList ->
                if (groupList.data?.size == 0)
                {
                    return@collect
                }

                groups = groupList.data!!
                feedFilter.group = groups.firstOrNull()?.guid
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add labels to the `collect` blocks and use them with `return` statement:

```
.collect collectLabel2@ { 
            // ...
            return@collectLabel2
            
            // ...        
}
```

Here label `collectLabel2` is added.

---

To eliminate multiple `collect` blocks you can try to use [`flatMapMerge`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html) or [`flatMapLatest`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) function:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    companyDataStore.getFromDataStore()
        .catch { e ->
            _snackBar.value = e.message
        }
        .flatMapMerge { company ->
            companyFeatures = company.features

            userClient.getGroupsByFeatures(companyFeatures)
                .catch { e ->
                    _snackBar.value = e.message
                }
        }
        .collect { groupList ->
            if (groupList.data?.size != 0) {
                    groups = groupList.data!!
                    feedFilter.group = groups.firstOrNull()?.guid
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was applying the label incorrectly. I'll give that flatMapMerge a try, that's a common thing I run into.

Comment: Depending on what they're trying to do, `flatMapLatest` might be more appropriate. Nested `collect` is almost certainly the wrong thing to do, because if the second flow is infinite as flows of that sort typically are, then the second and all subsequent items of the first flow will never be processed.

Comment: that's good to know, I've looked at this in the past but the articles I've found weren't very helpful in explaining it, I'll for sure switch to this going forward.